# CSS Path in Reactjs is wrong

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-bootstrap

I have observed that suddenly CSS path in my project is changed, I am not sure about the reason whether this is a configuration issue or any other, but because of the path CSS is taking too much time to load.

I have already tried to check imports and everything in the code but it seems proper

Please check the below image for path comparison between the new and the backup folder.

**New Path:**

[image]

**Old Path**

[image]

Note: I need the path to be like old where react convert the css to inline, this runs faster.

**Below is how I have imported my custom CSS in index.js:**

```
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import  './index.css';
import  './utilities/animate.css';

//react and redux related library
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store/index';

class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Route path='/' component={App} />
        );
    }
}
let rootElement = document.getElementById('app');
render(<Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter >
        <Main />
    </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>, rootElement);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: please can show the code where you call your css?

Comment: @Angelotti : It is imported in in my index.js like this `import  './index.css';` Updated more in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run  `npm update` and updated few packages, may be some of the packages were corrupted or outdated. This fixed my issue of performance and CSS loading slow.